# "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting FOR, LOCK, TABLE, VALUES, WITH etc error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MYSQL version 8.0.21 and am attempting to include a stored procedure that returns values greater than 50 from a column named #_of_pieces in a table called Art_Form but I keep getting the error above with the following query.

```
CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`` PROCEDURE `Pieces` (in `#_of_pieces` int)  
BEGIN
    select `#_of_pieces`
    from Art_Form
    where #_of_pieces > 50
END
```

I am following my professor's example to create procedures and do not know how to use the commands the error suggests. Can anyone shed some light on how to properly create this procedure.

Comment: You need `;` after `50`.

Comment: I've added the `;` and the error persists

Comment: You need backticks around `#_of_pieces` in the `WHERE` clause. Also, you shouldn't name your parameter variable the same as the table column. If you don't write ```Art_Form.`#_of_pieces` ``` it will use the parameter, not the column.

Comment: thank you this really helped